# Accessing model variable in validates, format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, format

I have the (simplified) model structure below:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    validates :full_name, format: { without: /[^a-zA-Z .,']+/, message: "cannot contain " + /[^a-zA-Z .,']+/.match(self.full_name).to_s}
end
```

I want to validate the user-provided full_name with a regular-expression and if the validation fails, I want to show which part of the full_name fails the regular-expression validation.

However, this returns "undefined method full_name" and I tried a bunch of other things for self.full_name but can't seem to figure out how to pass that data there.

How can I do this? Thanks for any feedback and answer, in advance.

Comment: you can write your own custom validation for this. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Comment: Is that my only way to achieve this? I want to stick to provided methods whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message), `Rails` allows to pass a `Proc` message. Thus, in your case it's possible to customise the message:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  validates :full_name,
    format: {
      without: /[^a-zA-Z .,']+/,
      message: ->(object, data) do
        "cannot contain " + /[^a-zA-Z .,']+/.match(object.full_name).to_s
      end
    }
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it when I get back on my pc.